# Haskell Parsec strange issue with multiple expression occurrences

Tags: haskell, parsec

here is the code which to my mind shouldn't cause any issue but for some reason does?

```
    program = expr8
        <|> seqOfStmt  

    seqOfStmt = 
        do list <- (sepBy1 expr8 whiteSpace)
            return $ if length list == 1 then head list else Seq list
```

I get 3 errors all in respect to 'list' not being in scope? 
It's probably blatantly obvious what is going wrong but I can't figure out why

If there are any alternatives to this I would greatly like to hear them !

Thanks in advance,
Seán

Comment: Your indentation looks broken (the lines following `program` and `seqOfStmt` should be indented further than the definition. Other than that it's very difficult to test your program without knowing what your other definitions are (e.g. where do `expr8`, `whiteSpace` and `Seq` come from?)

Comment: The problem is the type of the value you are returning: `if length list == 1 then head list else Seq list` -- let's say list is [a], then you return a in the then clause and something very different in the else clause (unless Seq is a constructor of type `[a] -> a`, which is not easily possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final line uses a tab character for indentation, while the other lines use spaces only.

You have tabs set to four spaces in your editor, but ghc uses eight character tab stops (just as terminals do).

Therefore your `return` line is parsed as a continuation of the previous line, and `list` is not yet in scope.

One easy way to fix this is to refrain from using tabs: use spaces only.

---

Once you've fixed that, your next error will probably be a type error: `head list` and `Seq list` have different types (unless perhaps you have redefined `head` for some reason). It's not clear why you want to treat the list differently if it contains only a single element.

Comment: that worked, however I now have an error with return, any thoughts? Clearly I'm not competent with Haskell

Comment: I'm not psychic! It would be a lot easier for me and everyone else if you posted your code exactly as it is now, and the full error message. Ideally post a new question.

Comment: Come on @dave4420, you could relly use the "Remote Login And Figure Out The Error" button everybody with more than 10k reputation gets provided by SO.

Comment: apologies for not providing enough information, just logged this new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133648/haskell-parsec-accounting-for-multiple-expression-occrrences-in-grammar)

Comment: @Ingo Bad news for you. That button is only provided for 17.5K rep.